# Probability Question Simple Qns

Tags: probability

Assume each of the four users is active for 20% of time and data generation rate of the four users are 400kbps, 600kbps, 700kbps and 800kbps, respectively.
Calculate the probability that the data generation exceed the maximum output rate of 1Mbps.

So basically only 400kbps + 600kbps will not exceed 1Mbps. all others will.
How do i calculate the probability in such as case ?

User active = 0.2
User inactive = 0.8

---- as what the previous comment suggest.
I understand how to caculate if the data generation rate are 500kbps,600kbps,700kbps,800kbps.
Because no any 2 combination will exceed the 1mbps.

Thus we can use binomial distribution to solve.
where

P(0 user also will not exceed) = (4 choose 0) * 0.8^4

P(1 user will not exceed) = (4 choose 1) * 0.2^1 * 0.8^3

Then we take 1-[P(0)+P(1)] to solve for the probability that data generation exceed the maximum output rate of 1Mbps.

however with a twist of the question. i don't really understand how to tackle it already.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: i've update on the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to split out the $400$ kbps user.

Let the activity of the four users be denoted by $U_4, U_6, U_7, U_8$.  We will assume that the usage patterns of the four users are independent; that is, the on-line status of any one of the users does not affect that of any other users, either individually or in conjunction.  That condition allows us to use the normal product of probabilities.  We'll also assume that $1000$ kbps equals $1$ Mbps, to forestall any objections about kibibytes and mebibytes. :-)

Then the desired probability is given by

$$
\begin{align}
P(B > 1 \text{ Mbps}) & = P(U_4)P(\text{at least one of } U_7, U_8) \\
                      & + [1-P(U_4)]P(\text{at least two of } U_6, U_7, U_8)
\end{align}
$$

If $U_4$, then we need at least one of $U_7$ or $U_8$, regardless of whether $U_6$ is active or not.

Hopefully, you'll be able to take it from here.

Comment: In general, with this small a number of cases (there are only $2^4 = 16$ different usage patterns), a good tactic is to simply enumerate the cases and see how you can simplify things.  Sort of like a Karnaugh map.

Comment: How do i calculate P(at least one of U7 & U8) ? Is it calculated as (2 choose 1)(0.2*0.8) ?